# Can't locate DBD/mysql.pm

Tags: perl

I’m rebuilding an old gaming server and have installed MySQL 5.5 and Active Perl.  It’s a Windows 2012R2 server and I use MySQL and Active Perl to populate activity to a website.

The gaming server is running and MySQL and the website is up but empty of player stats as the Perl script I run says:

```
c:\HLStatsX>perl hlstats.pl
install_driver(mysql) failed: Can't locate DBD/mysql.pm in @INC (you may 
need to install the DBD::mysql module) (@INC contains: C:/Perl64/site/lib 
C:/Perl64/lib) at (eval 10) line 3. Perhaps the DBD::mysql perl module 
hasn't been fully installed, or perhaps the capitalisation of 'mysql' isn't 
right.  Available drivers: CSV, DBM, ExampleP, File, Gofer, Mem, ODBC, 
Oracle, Pg, Proxy, SQLite, Sponge. at .//HLstats.plib line 152. c:\HLStatsX>
```

In my environment variables under PATH I have:

```
C:\Perl64\site\bin;C:\Perl64\bin;C:\Program Files 
(x86)\PHP\v5.5;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows 
;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32 
\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Serv
```

I know little about MySQL and Active Perl and have spent ages on Google to find a solution.

Has anyone seen this before?

I've just tried the manual install too:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZtn0.png)

Comment: see [Activestate documentation](https://www.activestate.com/blog/how-install-cpan-modules-activeperl/)

Comment: You should probably install that module...

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question, is this done through the manager as it’s not listed in there to install?

Comment: Sorry missed the first post, I will try this when I get home and post back.

Comment: I don't seem to have the option to paste a screenshot, but this is what I get: 
    c:\>ppm install DBD-mysql
    'ppm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.

    c:\>

Comment: Failed with this:

c:\ppm install DBD-mysql
syncing site PPM database with .packlists...done
ppm install failed: can't find any package that provides DBD-mysql

I've reinstall Active Perl too.

Comment: Huh, uninstalled active perl and then did a clean install of an older version and it worked.  I did try the latest version which didn't work again.  Time to move on I guess as it works.  Thanks for your help though.